# Отображение блока при наведении CSS

Tags: html, css

При наведении на элемент появляется контент. Как сделать так чтобы данные элементы оставались в одну линию по горизонтали, а контент просто появлялся снизу? (как на картинке). Без использования flexbox

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.content {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #ccc;
  padding: 5px;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}
.content:hover .hide {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  hover
  <p class="hide">
    Text
  </p>
</div>
<div class="content">
  hover
  <p class="hide">
    Text
  </p>
</div>
<div class="content">
  hover
  <p class="hide">
    Text
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Добавить `float: left` в `.content`?

Comment: а ещё есть способы? забыл уточнить что данные блоки находятся в контейнере. а с float они выпадают

Comment: А какие свойства в контейнера?

Comment: для удобства скину здесь. 
Если слишком много кода, обращайтесь, я сокращу объем, чтобы было удобнее.

https://codepen.io/st-iv/pen/vRqmWK

Comment: Да нет, все нормально. Добавил флоат и все отлично.

Answer (score 1):

```css
.content {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top; /* по умолчанию baseline */
  background: #ccc;
  padding: 5px;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}

.content:hover .hide {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  hover
  <p class="hide">
    Text
  </p>
</div>
<div class="content">
  hover
  <p class="hide">
    Text
  </p>
</div>
<div class="content">
  hover
  <p class="hide">
    Text
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

В блок `.content` добавить 
`vertical-align: top`